# SQL Server : optimization table design recommandation with huge data records

Tags: sql-server-2008

Somehow my database is too slow when writing.

Currently I have used 319MB which has 2,127,227 rows within it. The first couple days my computer was able to insert couple thousand rows per second and now it taking me forever to insert 1 thousand rows. Now it taking 165 seconds to insert 1 thousand rows (0.165 per row). I need to be able to insert 10,000 per minutes (0.006 per row)

Please see the design of my table  and server specs below and let me know if you can help me to optimize this.  Thank you.

```
Current usage report
Records 2,127,227
Reserveed KB 323,088
Data(KB) 177,088
```

My table designed is like this, I did index `[LoginID] ASC,[ProductID] ASC, [ProductModifiedDate]`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductTable](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductPrice] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [ProductModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProductCreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductTable] ON [dbo].[ProductTable] 
(
    [LoginID] ASC,
    [ProductID] ASC,
    [ProductModifiedDate] ASC
)
```

My insert statement is just a normal simple sql statement, there was nothing special to it.

My hardware:

I have a 2 Quad 2.83 Ghz with 16GB DDR3 RAM with SQL Server 2008 R2 express edition. The CPU is running at 25% capacity when insert these rows.

Please let me know how to optimize this table. I really need to be able to search through all of these columns so I think indexing these columns are very importance and I have to keep the row up to 30 days.

I thought the SQL Server Express edition can support 10GB of data.

Comment: Since you have the clustered index on a GUID column, your index will have a **terrible** amount of fragmentation - and it gets worse every time you insert more rows. You need to (a) at least rebuild the index to limit the fragmentation, or (b) even better: use something else besides a GUID as your clustering key. GUIDs are a horribly bad choice for a clustering key - see [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new record, how are you generating the UUID?

Using a truly random UUID can result in *very bad* index fragmentation. This is *extra painful* when it is a Clustered Index because the data (row) layout itself is affected.

See [NEWID vs NEWSEQUENTIALID](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32597/Performance-Comparison-Identity-x-NewId-x-NewSeque)

> The most striking is the number of writes required by the NEWID system function. This, coupled with the average page density of 69%, is evidence of the page splitting caused by the random distribution of inserts at the leaf level. As soon as a page fills up, it needs to be split into two pages of 50% each for the insert to complete. Not only has page splitting resulted in poor page density, it has fragmented the data pages quite badly (*there is a 99% probability that the next data page is not next to the current one*).

And that is for only 50k records :-) The above link also provides a TSQL snippet to show the table statistics.

Similarly, check the auxiliary index (and rebuild if required).